# Should I remove 4" of cellose insulation before adding fiberglass insulation?

Tags: insulation, attic

My attic currently has 4" of blown cellulose insulation (to the top of the 2x4 joists). I plan on sealing air leaks and adding R-38 batts. The home was built in 1977 in zone 5.

Should I remove the cellulose and use faced batts or should I top with unfaced? Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: Why aren't you blowing more cellulose? A continuous blanket usually beats all those seams in terms of performance, and cellulose is cheap.

Comment: How much harder is it to do wiring work in the attic after insulation is blown in? I’ve a number of someday projects that I’d prefer to not have to do before insulating.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's harder at all. Moving some cellulose aside and then flipping it back in place when you're done is easier than refitting a bunch of batts like a puzzle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would leave the cellulose in place and use unfaced batts so moisture is not trapped. A couple extra inches over the top would help reduce the heat from conducting through the wood.